# richface tree with selectitem (checkbox)

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tree, richfaces

I am trying to put checkbox in tree node. My code is as below.
I used richfaces - SC.

**In JSP page :**

```
<h:panelGrid>
<sc:tree value="#{templateCategoriesBackingBean.rootNode}">
</sc:tree>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**In BackingBean :**

```
private TreeNode<SelectItem> rootNode;
public TreeNode<SelectItem> getRootNode() {
rootNode = new TreeNodeImpl<SelectItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TreeNodeImpl<SelectItem> treeNodeImpl = new TreeNodeImpl<SelectItem>();
    treeNodeImpl.setData(new SelectItem(i, "Hello : "+i));
    rootNode.addChild(new Integer(i), treeNodeImpl);
}
return rootNode;
}
```

It shows nodes on screen but like below...

[image]

> How do I get actual checkbox?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried what is being suggested. but that's not what I want.
It definitely returns me a string and I can see label of my `SelectItem` in tree.

But what I want is like see [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeSelectionCheckbox.jsf).
This is a primefaces tree checkbox example. I want a similar using richfaces or myfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a method `toString()` for `SelectItem`.

Somthing like

```
class SelectItem {
  private String name;

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please give me more detail.

Comment: @Ketan what kind of "more detail" you need? You just have to edit your `SelectItem` class to add the `toString` method.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I tried it but what I want is not to see label of that SelectItem, instead a checkbox to be appended with tree view. Please see my update, I appended with question. By the way Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Roman C I tried it but what I want is not to see label of that SelectItem, instead a checkbox to be appended with tree view. Please see my update, I appended with question. By the way Thanks for your response.